# Can tefillin shel yad be worn on one's clothes?

Tags: tefilin, choleh-sick

Someone I know has a medical condition that prevents him from wearing tefillin on his bare arm. Can an *ones* wear the tefillin on his clothes, instead, or should he not wear this at all? If the 2nd answer, should he still wear the *rosh* tefillin alone?